# MYSQL import: Cannot get geometry object from data you send to the GEOMETRY field

Tags: mysql-workbench, mysql

I have recently upgraded to MySQL 5.7 and was trying to run a replication from 5.6 master. However the replication fails with the following error:

```
Error 'Cannot get geometry object from data you send to the GEOMETRY field' on query.
```

Turns out it also happens when I try to import data from the mysqldump. Table structure is as follows:

```
 CREATE TABLE `locations` (
  `location_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `country_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `locations_type_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `parent_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `importance` decimal(3,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1.00',
  `lat` decimal(10,7) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lng` decimal(10,7) DEFAULT NULL,
  `radius` decimal(6,3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `polygon` polygon DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`location_id`),
  KEY `name` (`name`,`locations_type_id`,`parent_id`,`lat`,`lng`),
  KEY `locations_type_id` (`locations_type_id`),
  KEY `name_2` (`name`(8)),
  KEY `country_id` (`country_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

It appears to me that the import is trying to insert some binary data into the polygon field but in fairness I have no idea how to make it work.

Any ideas?

Comment: I gave you a plus on this...any luck?  I have the same issue:
Cannot get geometry object from data you send to the GEOMETRY field

Comment: I actually had to downgrade to MySQL 5.6 to sort it out

Comment: Can import into 5.6 all day, no issues... but 5.7 is a nogo.

Comment: Do you have polygons in your data that have less than 4 points defined? see -  https://github.com/creof/doctrine2-spatial/issues/155

Answer (score 8):

If you can re-run mysqldump, try to add --hex-blob option to have all binary data exported as hex dump.

Comment: @wtanaka.com can you show an excerpt from your dump?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I am testing a hypothesis that this problem might somehow be related to dumping from 5.5 and importing into 5.7, so I am testing upgrading in place from 5.5 => 5.6 => 5.7 and then doing the dump/restore.  If I run into issues with that approach, I will try this suggestion again.