# Cannot insert WKB to POINT column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js, spatial

I'm building a Node.js app that manages points of interest in my area. I insert POIs by converting latlong coordinates using `wkx` into a WKB buffer which is then inserted into a `POINT` column in MySQL. The query is built with Knex.js. Here's how the query look like:

```
INSERT INTO `places` (`name`, `coordinate`)
    VALUES ('Null Island', X'00000000010100000000000000000000000000000000000000')
```

It throws out `Cannot get geometry object from data you send to the GEOMETRY field`.

I tinkered with it so it becomes this:

```
INSERT INTO `places` (`name`, `coordinate`)
    VALUES ('Null Island', UNHEX('00000000010100000000000000000000000000000000000000'))
```

But it still doesn't work. I finally get it to work only by using `ST_GEOMFROMTEXT(0 0)`. And it works even if I screw it around like this:

```
INSERT INTO `places` (`name`, `coordinate`)
    VALUES ('Null Island', UNHEX(HEX(ST_GEOMFROMTEXT('POINT(0 0)')))
```

What's wrong? How can I make it work directly from buffer?
I suspect my problem is similar with [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34311195/mysql-import-cannot-get-geometry-object-from-data-you-send-to-the-geometry-fiel).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [MySQL Reference Manual on Supported Spatial Data Formats](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gis-data-formats.html):

> Internally, MySQL stores geometry values in a format that is not identical to either WKT or WKB format. (Internal format is like WKB but with an initial 4 bytes to indicate the SRID.)

So, inserting WKB values (such as those generated by `wkx`) *cannot* be done directly. Instead, use `ST_GEOMFROMWKB()` as described [here.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gis-wkb-functions.html#function_st-geomfromwkb)